# Can't partition startup disk in Mavericks for Boot Camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I recently upgraded my computer to Mavericks (I believe I have the latest version, 10.9) and I've been trying for 2 days now to install Windows via Boot Camp on my computer, but it always fails at the Partitioning step.

I have tried multiple different things, such as…

- Partitioning via Disk Utility
- Going into the Recovery HD and trying to repair the HD
- `/fsck/sbin -fy` in Single-User mode
- I have used a Mountain Lion USB install to use the Disk Utility there

…but I keep ending up with the same errors:

- Partition map is broken
- Verification of the file system failed

When I try to repair it using Recovery HD I keep getting "Live file system repair is not supported" and there is basically no way for me to partition, unless I want to downgrade to another version of OS X which I don't feel like doing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the partition map on the drive is corrupt and needs to be repaired.

1. Backup all your data (possibly with a disk image of your startup disk partition) and boot into a separate disk (not Recovery HD).
2. Select your drive in Disk Utility, and choose the Partition tab.

   [image]
   [image]
3. Change Partition Layout to **1 Partition** or **2 Partitions**. This will erase the entire disk, replacing the corrupt partition map with a new one.
4. Click Apply.

Comment: would booting into a mountain lion usb installer work?

Comment: @SimonAndersson Yes it should

Comment: also what's the best way to backup my data if i don't have an external harddrive? :S the biggest USB i have is 32 gigabytes

Comment: @SimonAndersson This process will erase all data from your drive, but if you're lacking space, don't back up data you don't need (e.g. /System as they'd be replaced when you reinstall OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this without erasing my harddrive by just booting into single-user mode and repairing the actual Macintosh HD Partition, instead of the whole harddrive.